# Symfony - TCPdf - Unable to find template

Tags: php, symfony, tcpdf

I'm stuck with an annoying error with TCPdf and Symfony:

`request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template "" (looked into: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/app/Resources/views)." at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 128 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to find template \"\" (looked into: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/app/Resources/views). at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php:128, Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): Unable to find template \"\" (looked into: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/app/Resources/views). at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:215)"} []`

In my controller I just create a pdf and output it:

```
public function pdfAction()
{
    $pdf = ...;
    ...
    $pdf->output();
}
```

My best guess is that Symfony is trying to return a Response (but the output already gave one) and thus the error. However I cannot find how I should resolve this in Symfony. Any help or tips are welcome.

PS: The pdf works perfectly, only monologger that is spamming me with errors ..

**For future reference**:

This is how I solved it in the end:

```
$pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'I');
return new Response();
```

I tried many different options but this is the only one that doesn't trigger that error.

Comment: Maybe this will work - http://blog.lundscape.com/2015/04/using-tcpdf-with-symfony-2/

Answer (score 1):

With Symfony you need to return response as array.

Maybe this piece of code works:

```
$pdfOutput = $pdf->output();

return array('pdfOutput' => $pdfOutput); // or just try to return $pdf;

// If you don't use annotation : 
return $this->render('your-template.html.twig', array(
    'pdfOutput' => $pdfOutput
));
```

And in your template, if you want to result some things, your template looks like that :

```
{{ dump(pdfOutput) }}
```

**EDIT**

Try with a path as arguments

$pdf->Output("output.pdf", 'I');

[TCPDF output doc](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1)

Comment: I tried array, returning a new response etc. But once i call ->output() it gets fired of. Should I catch it with ob ?

Comment: You can try. Maybe you have to configure TCPdf with a template ? https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle. @RVandersteen see my edit

Comment: ob_start();
        $pdf->Output("output.pdf", 'I');
        ob_end_clean();

Comment: And still the pdf is outputted (yes i cleared cache)